# Correct JSON format for the JSON_LISTING_FEED product upload SP-API

Tags: json, feed, amazon-selling-partner-api

```
{
    "header": {
    "sellerId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "2.0",
    "issueLocale": "en_US"
},
"messages": [
{
    "messageId": 1,
    "sku": "TESTSKU",
    "operationType": "UPDATE",
    "productType": "LUGGAGE",
    "requirements": "LISTING",
    "attributes": {
       "item_name": [
       {
         "value": "TEST Title",
         "language_tag": "en_US",
         "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
       }
       ],
     "fulfillment_availability": [
     {
       "fulfillment_channel_code": "AMAZON_NA",
       "quantity": 10
     }
     ],
     "purchasable_offer": [
     {
       "currency": "US",
       "our_price": [
       {
         "schedule": [
         {
           "value_with_tax": 285.93
         }
         ]
       }
       ],
       "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
     }
     ]
   }
 }
```

]
}

This is currently how my JSON is formatted for the JSON_LISTING_FEED upload channel and whenever I go to upload the test product I can see it processing in seller central, and once it is done the report says I am missing a bunch of attributes for the product upload. If anyone could give me any help on what else I may need to add in the JSON for it to be recognized as a valid product please let me know.